# is TensorSharedVariable in theano initilized twice in function?

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

In theano, once the sharedvarialbe is initialized in one function, it will never be initialized again even if the function is accessed repeatedly, am I right?

```
def sgd_updates_adadelta(params,cost,rho=0.95,epsilon=1e-6,norm_lim=9,word_vec_name='Words'):

updates = OrderedDict({})
exp_sqr_grads = OrderedDict({})
exp_sqr_ups = OrderedDict({})
gparams = []
for param in params:
    empty = np.zeros_like(param.get_value())
    exp_sqr_grads[param] = theano.shared(value=as_floatX(empty),name="exp_grad_%s" % param.name)
    gp = T.grad(cost, param)    
    exp_sqr_ups[param] = theano.shared(value=as_floatX(empty), name="exp_grad_%s" % param.name)
    gparams.append(gp)
```

In the code above, the exp_sqr_grads variable and the exp_sqr_ups variable will not be initialized with zeros again when the sgd_updates_adadelta function is called the second time?

Comment: This is not valid python code. Is all what you have written under the `def` line supposed to be in the function? Please edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared variables are not static, if that is what you mean. My understanding of your code:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

global_list = []

def f():

    a = np.zeros((4, 5), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    b = theano.shared(a)
    global_list.append(b)
```

Copy and paste this into an IPython and then try:

```
f()
f()

print global_list
```

The list will contain two items. They are not the same object:

```
In [9]: global_list[0] is global_list[1]
Out[9]: False
```

And they don't refer to the same memory: Do

```
global_list[0].set_value(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5).astype(theano.config.floatX))
```

Then

```
In [20]: global_list[0].get_value()
Out[20]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]])

In [21]: global_list[1].get_value()
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Having established that initializing shared variables several times leads to different variables, here is how to update a shared variable using a function. We re-use the established shared variables:

```
s = global_list[1]
x = T.scalar(dtype=theano.config.floatX)
g = theano.function([x], [s], updates=[(s, T.inc_subtensor(s[0, 0], x))])
```

`g` now increments the top left value of `s` by `x` at every call:

```
In [7]: s.get_value()
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [8]: g(1)
Out[8]: 
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])]

In [9]: s.get_value()
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [10]: g(10)
Out[10]: 
[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])]

In [11]: s.get_value()
Out[11]: 
array([[ 11.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? It is not entirely clear. If it does, you should click the accept button. If not, please add clarifications.

Comment: Not exactly what I expected. But I think I figured it out. In theano ,the shared variables are initialized only once when the the update function in theano is compiled. Am I right?

Comment: You typically initialize a shared variable once. It can then be updated on function calls using and update dictionary. Is this what you are asking? It is still unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about the update parameter in theano.function(inputs, outputs, mode=None, updates=None, givens=None), once the update function is compiled, the shared variables will not be initialized again even if the update function is called multiple times.

Comment: It would be great if you could mention that somewhere in your question. I added something about updates to my answer.